# Where is PayPal's elusive IPN History?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have the IPN receiver on my server successfully receiving IPNs and re-posting them back to PayPal's server (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr) for validation. I am testing it using the IPN simulator and it always receives `INVALID`. So I've done the bulk of the work and got the servers talking. There's just a bit of fine polishing needed and I cannot debug this because I have no feedback. Where can I get this feedback?

PayPal's docs state the following:

"**Check your IPN history on paypal.com.** 
Your IPN history tells you whether PayPal sent a given IPN message and whether your listener responded to it. This page may also provide information about the status of the server on which your listener is running. If necessary, you can request that PayPal re-send a given IPN message via the IPN history page."
-- https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/

So I need to find this IPN history, right?  But what account are these IPN logs recorded? Do they definitely include IPNs generated using the simulator? If not what's the point and how does any dev debug? I've looked in the live merchant account, the sandbox merchant account, the sandbox payer account. But they all say there is no history of any IPNs being sent.

Just a side point: PayPal's sandbox is a nightmare because if you log out of one sandbox account you find yourself at the login page back on the live site. Similarly, you cannot login to the IPN simulator using a sandbox merchant account, only the live merchant account so you are forever having to login as live merchant to send the request, logout, login as sandbox, check the IPN history, find nothing, log back out, log in as live and repeat until you are insane. Then to further confuse things, the simulator sends IPNs from the address `buyer@paypalsandbox.com` SO MAKE UP YOUR MIND PAYPAL!!!! Is the IPN Simulator part of the sandbox or not? Once you have submitted one simulated IPN, it resets all the form values to defaults if you do need to enter an address of a valid sandbox payer account (The docs don't state whether or not you do, but I am cluching at straws here) you also have to copy and paste into boxes numerous times per request. Please please please PayPal, write you docs in a way that can be understood by someone who is not one of your colleagues. Explain what environment you need to be in at each stage of testing the IPN.

I am feeling very frustrated because this is not how development should be done. I am blindly trying things based on hunches, very unscientific and very inefficient.

Can anyone clarify (or point me to the part of the docs that clarifies) exactly how to debug `INVALID` responses please?

Answer (score 3):

OK. After some significant time I have come to the following conclusions:

The IPN Simulator is *NOT* really part of the sandbox. It is useful for hitting quick lightweight tests to check PayPal's server can talk to yours but that is about it. It is far from a true payment process simulator! The solution to debugging your IPN validation process is to start the payment simulation process from the basket submission stage with a few very important values set to sandbox environment.

**1)** Firstly, log in to https://developer.paypal.com/ using your LIVE business account username and password. Click on `Applications` > `Sandbox Accounts` https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts and create 2 sandbox accounts:

Create one **Merchant/Business** Sandbox Account, this is going to be our fake shop. For example **alansugar@yourdomain.example.com**

Then, create one **Personal Sandbox** Account, this is going to be our fake customer. For example **ladygaga@yourdomain.example.com**

We are going to use this fake shop and this fake customer to play in the sandbox...

**2)** Set up the basket page on your server (the one that submits to PayPal) with your Merchant/Business Sandbox account's address in the `business` field and PayPal's sandbox domain in the `action` property of the FORM element. Like so...

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">
    <input type="hidden" value="alansugar@yourdomain.example.com" name="business">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_note">
    <input type="hidden" value="GBP" name="currency_code">
    <input type="hidden" value="GB" name="lc">
    <input type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF" name="bn">
    <input type="hidden" value="bo14-9097200" name="invoice">
    <input type="hidden" value="monkey" name="custom">
    <input type="hidden" value="A nice pair of trousers" name="item_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="Some socks to match">
    <input type="hidden" value="25.0" name="amount">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="no_shipping">
    <input class="buyButton" type="image" border="0" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online." name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif">
    <img width="1" border="0" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="">
</form>
```

**3)** Submit the basket and when you see the PayPal payment page (your browsers address bar will be accessing the www.sandbox.paypal.com domain) use your fake customer account to pay.

**4)** Log in to https://developer.paypal.com/ using your LIVE account. Click on `Applications` > `Sandbox Accounts` and click the `Enter Sandbox site` link. Now, whilst your browser is still logged into your main live account, you can kind of secondarily log in to a deeper layer using the sandbox accounts username and password (very confusing). Of course just to confuse you, the `Username` and `Password` boxes in the top right will be pre-populated with your live account's details. Wipe these and use the sandbox Merchant/Business account's username and password. Now click on `History` > `IPN History` and you can see the requests that were posted to your server. You should be able to debug nicely using this information. If IPN is not enabled on your Merchant/Business Sandbox Account yet it will give you instructions to go to a settings page and enable it. Do that. Obviously any payments before that point will not have triggered IPNs.

I hope this description helps anyone who, like me, found that the Official PayPal Docs read like a book with half the pages missing!

Comment: Agreed. It seems to me that the IPN simulator is basically useless after the stage where you get your first IPN validation success. It would be considerably more useful if it handled all the transaction types, and if it remembered values from the previous transaction.

Answer (score 3):

To access IPN notification history in PayPal sandbox, login at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com with your test merchant account.
Navigate to "My Account/Profile"
in "Selling preferences" section it has a link "Instant Payment Notification preferences"
On that page there is a link to "IPN History page".

I'm not sure if they recently have added this to the sandbox, but I agree it's pretty cumbersome.